# Rotary knob that triggers events when rotated in jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, angle

I'm trying to create a few interactive rotary knobs like those you could find in vintage TVs and radios. I'm using [KnobKnob.js](https://github.com/martinaglv/KnobKnob) to allow the user to rotate. It sometimes behaves weirdly, but given the paucity of plugins available for this particular need and my lack of time, I decided to give it a go anyway.

What I'd like to do is change the source of a video depending on **the angle of rotation** of the rectangular part of the knob, or `<div id="centralKnob">` in my code, to replicate the behavior of a Channels knob. The user should also be able to just click the surrounding links to do that.

[image]

So, I thought the best way to do that would be to change the source based on the current rotation angle of the knob. As I'm pretty new to JS/jQuery, I had no idea how to get the angle of an element, so I looked around and found [this article](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/). What they do:

```
var el = document.getElementById("centralKnob");

var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);

var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
         "Either no transform set, or browser doesn't do getComputedStyle";

var values = tr.split('(')[1];
values = values.split(')')[0];
values = values.split(',');

var values = tr.split('(')[1];
whatever = tr.split(')')[0];
whatever = tr.split(',');

var a = values[0];
var b = values[1];
var c = values[2];
var d = values[3];


var angle = Math.round(Math.asin(b) * (180/Math.PI));
```

This should give the current angle of the knob.
But how do I make it so that the angle is recalculated every time the user changes it and the video source gets changed whenever the knob is positioned between X(deg) and Y(deg)?

Thanks in advance. I also welcome any suggestion or advice as to how to make the whole thing work better, especially how to allow the user to rotate the knob smoothly. Also, I know that rotary dials and knobs aren't such a good idea in webdesign and aren't the best thing to control with a mouse, but this is more of a technical challenge than an actual public website.

Answer (score 5):

I made something like this in the past.

http://jsfiddle.net/gTDdp/16/

(With some tweaking it should be possible, to create a rotating knob.)
I added touch events to for mobile devices

```
    var dragging = false

    $(function() {
        init();
        var target = $('#target')
        var offset_x = -256;
        var offset_y = 356;
        var angle = 0;
        var startAngle;
        var slices = 8;
        var sliceAngle = 360 / slices;
        target.mousedown(function(e) {
            var mouse_x = e.pageX;
            var mouse_y = e.pageY;
            var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - offset_x, mouse_y - offset_y);
            dragging = true
            startAngle = ((radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90) - angle;
        })
        $(document).mouseup(function() {
            dragging = false;
            var slice = (angle + (sliceAngle/2)) / sliceAngle;
            if(slice < 0){
                slice = 12 + slice;
            }else if(slice > 12){
                slice = 12 - slice;
            }

            // Move circle in perfect position
            angle = (Math.floor(slice) * (360 / slices));
            target.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
            target.css('-moz-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            target.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
            target.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '50%, 50%');
            target.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
            target.css('-o-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            target.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
            target.css('-ms-transform-origin', '50% 50%');

            alert(Math.floor(slice));
        })
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
            if (dragging) {
                var mouse_x = e.pageX;
                var mouse_y = e.pageY;
                var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - offset_x, mouse_y - offset_y);
                var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
                angle = degree - startAngle;
                if(angle < 0){
                    angle = 360 + angle;   
                }else if(angle > 360){
                    angle = 360 - angle;
                }
                target.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
                target.css('-moz-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
                target.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
                target.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '50%, 50%');
                target.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
                target.css('-o-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
                target.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
                target.css('-ms-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            }
        })
    })


    function touchHandler(event)
    {
     var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";

         switch(event.type)
    {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
        case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
        default: return;
    }        
    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                      first.screenX, first.screenY,
                      first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                      false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
    }

    function init()
    {
       document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
       document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
       document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
       document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);    
    }
```

Comment: man you did all this work and he didn't even upvote you, accept your answer, OR reply..